# How to import methods from another file python kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to import methods from another file python kivy and getting the next error:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - TypeError: __import__() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
  File "C:\Users\liort\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 63, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

without the line : `from scripts.LeptonAPI import initCam, startLepton, stopLepton` the kivy is working.

what i did wrong?

where is my mistake?

here is my code:

```
import cv2
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from datetime import datetime

from scripts.LeptonAPI import initCam, startLepton, stopLepton

# cameraID2 = 0  # id of FLIR Lepton
cameraID1 = 1  # id of SMI Depstech


class SMICamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, parent, capture, **kwargs):
        super(SMICamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.capture = capture  # data to read
        self.parent = parent  # this object's parent (= box layout)
        self.started = False  # start state
        self.TurnOn = False  # to turn on camera

    # starts the "Camera", capturing at 30 fps by default
    def start(self, fps=30):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0 / fps)

    def update(self, dt):
        ret, self.frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            if self.started:
                out.write(self.frame)
            # convert it to texture
            image_texture = self.get_texture_from_frame(self.frame, 0)
            # display image from the texture
            self.texture = image_texture
            self.parent.ids['imageCamera'].texture = self.texture

    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.update)

    def get_texture_from_frame(self, frame, flipped):
        buffer_frame = cv2.flip(frame, flipped)
        buffer_frame_str = buffer_frame.tostring()
        image_texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        # print('(' + str(frame.shape[1]) + ';' + str(frame.shape[0]) + ')')
        image_texture.blit_buffer(buffer_frame_str, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        return image_texture

    def start_stop_RecordVideo(self):
        self.started = not self.started


class CameraScreen(Screen):
    turnOn = False
    # initialize the "Camera"
    SMICamera = Image(source='logo.jpg')

    def startCamera(self, imageCamera, buttonTurnOn, buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonBack):
        if not self.turnOn:
            self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraID1)
            self.SMICamera = SMICamera(self, self.capture)
            imageCamera = self.SMICamera
            self.SMICamera.start()
            # Set as started, so next action will be 'Pause'
            self.turnOn = True
            buttonTurnOn.text = 'Turn Off'
            # when started, let start enabled
            buttonStop.disabled = False  # enabled
            # Enable the Start (button)
            buttonStart.disabled = False
            # Prevent the back (button)
            buttonBack.disabled = True
            initCam(filename,now)
        else:  # press on TurnOff
            self.turnOn = False  # stop what was "started"
            buttonTurnOn.text = 'Turn ON'
            self.SMICamera.stop()
            # Reset camera to home image
            self.SMICamera.stop()
            self.SMICamera = Image(source='logo.jpg')
            imageCamera.source = self.SMICamera.source
            imageCamera.reload()
            # Prevent the Stop (button)
            buttonStop.disabled = True
            # Prevent the Start (button)
            buttonStart.disabled = True
            # Enabled the back (button)
            buttonBack.disabled = False
            # Release the capture
            self.capture.release()

    # start to make a video and run Lepton Camera
    def startVideo(self):
        if self.turnOn:  # Was running at click
            self.SMICamera.start_stop_RecordVideo()
            startLepton()
            # LeptonCam.startLepton()
            # runpy.run_path(path_name='LeptonAPI.py')

    # stop the video
    def stopVideo(self):
        self.SMICamera.start_stop_RecordVideo()
        stopLepton()
        # LeptonCam.stopLepton()


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def exitApp(self):
        MainApp.stop()


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screenManager = ScreenManager()
        screenManager.add_widget(MainScreen(name="main"))
        screenManager.add_widget(CameraScreen(name="camera"))
        return screenManager


# Start the Camera App
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

to import a python file to another, the syntax is

```
from pythonfile import classesyouwanttoimport
```

- do not add the `.py` extension while importing
- make sure the `pythonfile` being imported *doesn't have a* `main` function

Now, the code you've posted

```
from scripts.LeptonAPI import initCam, startLepton, stopLepton
```

is looking for a file `LeptionAPI.py` in the folder `scripts` and then importing `functions` `initCam`, `startLepton`, `stopLepton`

is it what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm trying to control another cam that connects to my lap from the GUI I built.
I have two cams that working together, and separate them into two files.